# parsing a nested Json in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, uitableview

i just get started with Ios programming, and i have to parse a nested Json file and extract the items and lables, the problem is i have to display the list of the items on a tableview and refresh my tableview everytime i click on a row of my table view:
i did display the first list of my items but i'm trying to display my nested items and display them on my "new" tableview:
here are a simple of my JSON code and my objective-c code:

```
"results": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "0100",
        "label": "Actualités",
        "cover": "http://XXXX_01.jpg",
        "coverFrom": "XXX-03",
        "coverTo": "2031-CCC18",
        "coverOrder": 1,
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "0101",
            "label": "Actualité / Infos",
            "cover": "http://XXXX.jpg",
            "coverFrom": "2014XXX-24",
            "coverTo": "2031-XXXX18",
            "coverOrder": 1,
            "items": [

            ]
          },
```

and my RootViewContoller contain this code of the function connectionDidFinishiongLoading**

```
 // we will follow the format of our nested JSON
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataRequest options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *results = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
    NSArray *arrayOfItems = [results objectForKey:@"items"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfItems) {

        //NSArray *ide = [diction objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *label = [diction objectForKey:@"label"];

       // add new object founded
        [array addObject:label];

        }
    // reload my tableview

    [[self tableView]reloadData];


   // myParsingResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataRequest options:nil error:nil];
    [[self tableView]reloadData];
```

Comment: Where are you exactly blocked?

Comment: Can you pls add more info about how you want to display them?

Comment: I think the key to solve the problem is to use a table view controller which is capable to push an new instance of the same table view controller, when tabbing an "items" row. What you eventually get is a "dynamic" hierarchy of table view controllers. Defining this with segues is possible.

Comment: you could use the open source project [Mantle](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle) for parsing/mapping json, it's very simple to use!

Comment: i want to display all the parent items then when i click on each item i get the sub item of each one, and i'm blocked when i click on each row i don't get a new instance of my tableview but the old one with th same items (and not the sub-items)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, try something like that:

```
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataRequest options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *results = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
NSArray *array = [results objectForKey:@"items"];

NSMutableArray *arrayLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionnary *dicoTemp = [array objectAtIndex:0];
while([dicoTemp objectForKey:@"items"])
{
    arrayLabels addObject:[[dicoTemp objectForKey:@"items"] objectForKey:@"label"];
    NSArray *arrayTemp = [dicoTemp objectForKey:@"items"];
    dicoTemp = [arrayTemp objectAtIndex:0]; //I don't know how you JSON ends, you may have to check if [arrayTemp count] > 0. I presumed that at the end, there was no object for key "items"
}

[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

That a weird nested JSON response, in my opinion.

Comment: the entire of my Json is the same you will have items nested into items and so on! but what i don't undestand, is what i will display in my tableviews ??? the array temp or the arraylabels, because i need it in reurning the numberOfRowsInSection (in each section) and in cellDorRowAtIndexPath !!

Comment: According to your code, you only added "labels" to `array`. So I guess that was the "datasource" of your tableView. But you could place an NSDictionnary in it, and use it "as a datasource". So you could start by using/showing only `arrayLabels`.

Comment: @user3511071 I think the problem here is your JSON is too weird, why do you nest Items like that? you should adjust that JSON

Comment: i can't! it's a project that they gave me! they want me to parse this weird nested Json! and all the solution that i used didn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

Try this one...

```
 NSError *error = nil;

        NSURL *Url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"Your URL"];

        jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

        if(jsonData==Nil){
            UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please check your internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else{

            NSDictionary *dataDictionary =[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
            dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

            [array addObject:[[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"items"] valueForKey:@"label"]];

        }
```

and reloads your tableview.